# How to access content of a tab from firefox addon

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tabs, firefox-addon

In my addon I find the tab I want to operate and then try to access the elements of it.
Currently I am finding the tab I need by

```
    var b = this.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

    // qqDPSWD This allows for correct window targeting.

    var foundW = null;
    var en = this.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
      var w = en.getNext();
      if ((w.title && w.title.indexOf(parameters['title_identifier']) != -1) ||
          (w.document && w.document.title.indexOf(parameters['title_identifier']) != -1))
      {
        var doc = w.document;
        var temp2 = doc.getElementById("myframe");
        foundW = temp2.contentWindow;
      }
    }
```

temp2 is null though the tab does have an iframe with id myframe.

I get the object doc as an XUL object but doc.getElementById("myframe") is null. Currently I have an html file opened in the desired tab with the desired iframe residing inside the html page loaded in the main tab. I am able to identify the tab properly but couldn't return the iframe window. How do I do it?

I tried looking at the documentation for browsing between the tabs but couldn't find right answer in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code

Node I am working on https://github.com/sebuilder/se-builder/blob/master/seleniumbuilder/components/command_processor.js#L10103 and want to replace

```
    foundW = w;
```

with

```
    foundW = w.document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow
```

as unlike the open source project where he wants to return the tab window I want to return the iframe window present inside the tab he returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually going through all tabs, you are just going through the FIREFOX windows (called CHROME windows) (not the browser and its window inside each tab).

In your code. `var doc = w.document` is the CHROME document of the FIREFOX window (not the browser inside the tab). So `w.title` of the FIREFOX window will be the title of the currently selected tab (probably followed by ' - Mozilla Fireox' can you verify this for me? im guessing here)

temp2 is null because your frame is in the BROWSER IN TAB window which is the HTML document. So if your tab is currently selected you would get it like this `w.gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.contentwindow` this will be the html window. `w.selectedTab` is the actual tab element that you click at top, it has a property called `linkedBrowser` which holds the "HTML" browser which is inside this tab. (i put html

so to fix your code below:

```
var b = this.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

// qqDPSWD This allows for correct window targeting.

var foundW = null;
var en = this.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
  var w = en.getNext();
  if ((w.title && w.title.indexOf(parameters['title_identifier']) != -1) ||
      (w.document && w.document.title.indexOf(parameters['title_identifier']) != -1))
  {
    var doc = w.gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.contentDocument;
    var temp2 = doc.getElementById("myframe");
    foundW = doc.defaultView; //im not sure what you want foundW to be, the chrome window? or the tab html window? if you want html window or you can do doc.defaultView OR w.gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow BUT if you want the chrome window it would be w
  }
}
```

*HOWEVER* your code has a problem, its not going through all tabs in each window, its only going through the currently selected tab.

This is how you would do it for each tab in each window, read the comments carefully, also i took out your ugly if statement lol it was making things sloppy. Just put it back i replaced with `/*your if statement*/` for easyiness for me to make example below

```
var b = this.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

 // qqDPSWD This allows for correct window targeting.

var foundW = null;
var en = this.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
    var w = en.getNext();
    //we know for sure that all your windows have gBrowser element because you are getting enumerator for 'navigator:browser', but its not necessary for it to have tabContainer, for example a pop up window with no tabs in it
    if (w.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
        for (var i = 0; i < w.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes.length; i++) { //this itereates through each tab element in the tab bar (so the thingies you click)
            var tab = w.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[i];
            var tabBrowser = tab.linkedBrowser;
            var tabDoc = tabBrowser.contentDocument;
            var tabWin = tabDoc.defaultView; //OR you can do tabBrowser.contentWindow
            if ( /*if statement here*/ ) {

                var temp2 = tabDoc.getElementById("myframe");
                foundW = tabWin; //im not sure what you want here so i set it to the html window

                w.focus(); //if you want to focus this FIREFOX window which is chrome window do this:
                w.gBrowser.selectedTab = tab[i]; //if you want to select this tab then do this

            }
        }
    } else {
        //it has no tabContainer so its like a popup window with no tabs so our browser elment is just gBrowser, ill use same var names as above to keep things straight for you
        var tabBrowser = w.gBrowser;
        var tabDoc = tabBrowser.contentDocument;
        var tabWin = tabDoc.defaultView; //OR you can do tabBrowser.contentWindow
        if ( /*if statement here*/ ) {
            var temp2 = tabDoc.getElementById("myframe");
            foundW = tabWin; //im not sure what you want here so i set it to the html window

            w.focus(); //if you want to focus this FIREFOX window which is chrome window do this:
            //w.gBrowser.selectedTab = tab[i]; //no tabs in this window so if you do w.focus() on line above it will focus this properly
        }
    }
}
```